# Error al conectar API con token y Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

estoy tratando de conectar a un servicio, mediante el siguiente codigo:

```
var token = mitoken;
var parametros = {
        "dni" : dni
  };
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url:  miURL,
      data: parametros,
      headers: {'CSRF-TOKEN': token},
      success: function(rpta){
        alert("conecto!!!");           
      },
      error: function(rpta){
         var msj = JSON.stringify(rpta);
         alert("Error en la operación.\n\n"+msj);
      }
  });
```

Pero entra al error y me sale readyState:0 ResponseText y otros mas...que esta pasando??

Answer (score 0):

Según en la documentación de [AJAX - Server Response](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_response.asp) `readyState=0` quiere decir que no se pudo iniciar la petición http (tu navegador es incapaz de comunicarse con el servidor).

Así que asegúrate que tu url cumpla con todos los parámetros validos para hacer la petición (por ejemplo: La disponibilidad de la url, que sea el dominio correcto), también la propia conectividad del cliente.

También cabe destacar que deberías empezar a utilizar tecnologías y apis mas modernas para realizar tus peticiones ya que Ajax ya esta prácticamente esta o va en vías de obsolescencia, [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) ya es estándar y es una forma mas fácil y lógica de manejar peticiones según el modelo de JS moderno, también esta [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) que no es estándar ya que es parte de Vue pero es mucho mas potente y fácil de usar que fetch (si es que hay algo mas fácil que fetch, ya entiendes) como no es estándar no es parte de window y no es soportado por los navegadores nativamente pero puedes utilizar la librería en el navegador y aun así es muy rápido.

Ahora realmente, lo que puede estar pasando es que la conexión entre el cliente y la API es inestable, por lo que realmente es una pregunta incierta de responder ya que requiere un poco campo, tal vez puedas actualizar tu pregunta y aportar algunas capturas o tu consola entera al momento del error, por ahora te recomiendo que utilices fetch y me digas que tal te fue.

**Acá que dejo un ejemplo para que lo implementes rápido con un POST**:

```js
var token = 'mitoken';
var body = {
  "dni" : dni
};

fetch(myUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'CSRF-TOKEN': token
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(body)
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => {
  console.log("Petición post ", json)
})
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: Bueno, al parecer no funciona, te comento que en el postman si me funciona y opor url tmabien, ah el metodo es GET

http://myurl/dni?token=mytoken

asi me arroja el json que quiero

{"dni":"xxx","nombres":"AAA","apellidoPaterno":"BBB","apellidoMaterno":"CCC","codVerifica":"7"}

alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Puedes  ver los detalles de la petición en postman? Es decir la estrutura de la petición en codigo

Comment: Ya intentaste consumir otras apis? privadas o publicas, para ver que esta pasando, intenta añadir mode:"cors" a la configuración de tu petición con fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Este es mi código corregido y funcionando:

```
var token = myToken;
var dni = myDNI;
var url = myURL;

  var urlfinal = url+'/'+dni +'?token='+token;

  fetch(urlfinal)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((out) => {

        console.log('Output: ', out);
        var length = Object.keys(out).length; //numero de elementos
        if (length>0) {
          $('#nombres').val(out.nombres);
        } else {
          $('#nombres').val('');
        }

    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Al fin pude conectarme agregando el token como una paramatro mas, muchas gracias por sus aportes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>APIS</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mostrarAPI(){
var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
  var parametros = {            
        "name" : 'Patricia Lebsack'
  };
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },        
    body: JSON.stringify(parametros)
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log('Peticion post ',myJson);
    $('#nombres').val(myJson.name);
    //alert("entro!!");
  });
}
</script>
<body onload="mostrarAPI();">
<input type="text" id="nombres" name="">
</body>
</html>
```

Es un api libre y parametro "name", pero no conecta

Comment: No tienes que añadir una respuesta cada vez que necesites actualizar tu codigo podría bajarte reputación, solamente edita la pregunta y aclara que es un edit, avisa a la persona que lo necesita y listo, o aún mejor, si solo es un snippet simplemente ponlo en otra página como playcode o jsfiddle y pasa la URL respondiendo el comentario.

Comment: Estás usando mal fetch, primero las peticiones get no llevan body si son parámetros query de URL simplemente colocalos en la URL con el formato correspondiente ya sea directamente o dinámicamente. Por ejemplo `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?mame=un+nombre&ley=unakey`, el body es para peticiones que necesiten payloads grandes del cliente al servidor, como los POST, segundo:

Comment: Lee la documentación de fetch y podrás ver que el primer resolver, es decir el primer then se utiliza solo para convertir los datos a su formato con los métodos internos de del objeto de respuesta fetch como data.json() o simplemente para ejecutar código pero no utilizar la data para nada, simplemente haz esto `fetch(foo...).then(res => res.json()).then(resconvertida  => {foo})` nota que primero convertimos al formato en la primera promesa y luego es que utilizamos la respuesta.

Comment: [Mira este ejemplo](https://playcode.io/575420) donde uso fetch correctamente, fíjate qu si hay respuesta, un saludo.